# Parse php input file upload - not working

Tags: php, file, input, mamp

I am having issues with File uploads, PHP and Parse, although I haven't introduced the Parse part yet. I have a simple form with an input type=file element.

```
 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="inputFirstName" />
```

When I try to grab a file from the $_FILES array after posting back to the page, the array is empty. All of the other form elements post fine.

I am developing locally using MAMP. I have checked the php.ini file, and File Uploads is turned on. Anything else I should check or turn on?  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Full form below.

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form">

                    <?php if($formPosted) : ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10" id="formAlert<?php echo $type; ?> ">
                            <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $messageType ?>" role="alert">
                                <?php echo $message; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputProfilePicture" class="col-md-3 control-label">Picture</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputProfilePicture" name="inputProfilePicture">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name *</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="hidden" id="inputType" name="inputType" value="<?php echo $type; ?>">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputLastName" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name *</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" name="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email *</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPhone" class="col-md-3 control-label">Phone</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" pattern='\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password *</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUserType" class="col-md-3 control-label">User Type *</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="inputUserType" name="inputUserType" required="required">
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
                                <?php 
                                    $userTypeQuery = new ParseQuery("UserType");
                                    $results = $userTypeQuery->find();

                                    for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
                                        $role = $results[$i];
                                        echo "<option value='" . $role->get("name") . "'>" . $role->get("name") . "</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-8">
                          <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"></button> -->
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create New <?php echo ucfirst($type); ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

PHP Code

```
 var_dump($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` tag.

Comment: Well... it was that simple. Thought I had done that, but didn't realize it was a typo.  Thanks @MrZebra.